# MVC3 C# Custom HtmlHelper for input with validation, both client and server side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, html-helper

I have seen some similar questions to this, but they seem to be for older versions of MVC and i have had no luck working out how to apply them to MVC3.

Basically i have written a nice little htmlhelper that will display a chosen parameter for the current model, much like `@Html.DisplayFor()` does, except that with mine there is an edit button next to it (forgive the lack of styling in these examples!):

[image: button example]

when this button is clicked it will do one of those "pop-ups" where an editor field is displayed and the rest of the page is greyed out a bit using some simple jquery:

[image: popup example]

this is my helper:

```
    public static HtmlString PopUpEditorFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, bool textarea = false)
    {
        string id = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));

        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);

        var Display = new TagBuilder("span");
        Display.MergeAttribute("class", "Display");
        Display.InnerHtml = metadata.Model.ToString();

        var Edit_Button = new TagBuilder("span");
        Edit_Button.MergeAttribute("class", "Edit_Button");
        Edit_Button.InnerHtml = " Edit";// change to use resources file 

        var Display_Container = new TagBuilder("div");
        Display_Container.MergeAttribute("class", "Display");
        Display_Container.InnerHtml = Display.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal) + Edit_Button.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        var legend = new TagBuilder("legend");
        legend.InnerHtml = "Edit " + metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName;

        var Editor_Box_Input = new TagBuilder("input");
        Editor_Box_Input.MergeAttribute("class", "Editor_Box");
        Editor_Box_Input.MergeAttribute("id", id);
        Editor_Box_Input.MergeAttribute("name", id);
        Editor_Box_Input.MergeAttribute("type", "text");
        Editor_Box_Input.MergeAttribute("value", metadata.Model.ToString());

        var Editor_Box_Textarea = new TagBuilder("textarea");
        Editor_Box_Input.MergeAttribute("class", "Editor_Box");
        Editor_Box_Input.MergeAttribute("id", id);
        Editor_Box_Input.MergeAttribute("name", id);
        Editor_Box_Input.MergeAttribute("type", "text");
        Editor_Box_Textarea.InnerHtml = metadata.Model.ToString();

        var Buttons = new TagBuilder("div");
        Buttons.MergeAttribute("class", "Buttons");
        Buttons.InnerHtml = QuestJSButton(html, "Cancel", "Option Cancel").ToString() + QuestJSButton(html, "Save", "Submit Save").ToString();

        var fieldset = new TagBuilder("fieldset");
        fieldset.InnerHtml += legend.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        fieldset.InnerHtml += !textarea 
            ? Editor_Box_Input.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) 
            : Editor_Box_Textarea.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        fieldset.InnerHtml += Buttons.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        var form_styled = new TagBuilder("div");
        form_styled.MergeAttribute("class", "Editor form_styled");
        form_styled.InnerHtml = fieldset.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        var Editor_BG = new TagBuilder("div");
        Editor_BG.MergeAttribute("class", "Editor_BG");
        Editor_BG.InnerHtml = form_styled.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        var PopUp_Editor = new TagBuilder("div");
        PopUp_Editor.MergeAttribute("class", "PopUp_Editor");
        PopUp_Editor.MergeAttribute("id", id);
        PopUp_Editor.InnerHtml = Editor_BG.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal) + Display_Container.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        return PopUp_Editor.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal).ToHtmlString();
    }
```

which is just called like a normal helper:

```
@Html.PopUpEditorFor(model => model.property)
```

and produces the following html:

```
        <div class="PopUp_Editor" id="property_id">
          <div class="Display">
            <span class="Display">property_value</span>
            <span class="Edit_Button">Edit</span>
          </div>
          <div class="Editor_BG">
            <div class="Editor form_styled">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Edit Salutation</legend>
                <input class="Editor_Box" id="property_id" name="property_id" type="text" value="property_value" />
                <div class="Buttons">
                  <span class="Option Cancel">Cancel</span>
                  <span class="Submit Save">Save</span>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

this works nicely, except that i would like to make MVC3's awesome client/server side validation work with it, and i have no idea how to go about doing this. My goal would be to have any validation error messages displayed below both the display and the input, and for the input to get the classes needed to style it as any other htmlhelper input would be in the case of validation error like this:

[image: validation example]

**UPDATE**

I am pretty sure all i need to do is to make my helper include the requisite html attributes and span elements, here is the HTML generated automatically when you add a view with the "Edit" template:

```
<div class="editor-field">
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-email="This is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="You must provide an e-mail address." id="Email_Address" name="Email_Address" type="text" value="example@domain.com" />
</div>
<div class="editor-validation">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email_Address" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

so basically i need to know what the correct way of applying this to my helper is, and if possible make the framework do most of the work for me.

Answer (score 5):

There is a method on the HtmlHelper that you can use in your helper method to get the validation attributes on the model's property.

```
IDictionary<string, object> valAttributes = htmlHelper.GetUnobtrustiveValidationAttributes(propertyName, metaData);
```

Then you can loop through that collection and merge those attributes just like you're already doing with the others.

Answer (score 1):

As you are no doubt aware, you need to get some javascript (usually jQuery) to run on the client to get the awesome client-side validation of which you speak. Sometimes this can be generated by the framework and sometimes you need to write it yourself.

Have you seen this example by brad Wilson? http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

Here is another example which is both complete and also quite short: http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/2012/04/21/MVC3-Custom-Client-Side-Validation-with-Unobtrusive-Ajax.aspx

**EDIT:** If you want to use the standard validation, make sure you have these scripts referenced:

You need this in your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

and this in your page (or a master page):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Finally, remember if you are dynamically changing stuff (e.g. loading something via ajax or whatever) then you need to reparse the unobtrusive validation like this:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('formid'));
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that the JavaScript is already in place as it is working for standard HtmlHelpers, I think I just need to make sure that the correct html attributes are applied to the input fields and the correct span elements are in place to display the messages, see update.

Comment: Also I think i should clarify that the validation doesn't need to be custom, as I only need to use the built in ones like required and maxlength.

Comment: I have the validation working fine for most things, i even have it working with some custom attributes like "date must be after". I just do not know how do generate the correct DOM with a custom HTML helper.

Comment: Have you tried editing the raw HTML that is spat out by your helper? Presumably you can add the `data-` attributes to that?

Comment: I guess i can, but i was hoping there was at least a way of generating them automatically. I don't mind creating the spans and inserting the attributes my self, but I do not want to hard code the attributes